# Python 3.6 Не распознает русские символы

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, request

Python 3.6, PyCharm Community 2017.1, Windows

Пытаюсь получить с веб-страницы ее HTML-код для дальнейшего парсинга через BeautifulSoup вот такой функцией:

```
def get_page(group, week='now'):
    url = 'https://ifspo.ifmo.ru/schedule/get?num=g6&week=now.html'
    response = requests.get(url)
    web_page = response.text
    print(web_page)
    return web_page
```

но, когда я ее вывожу, то наблюдаю вот такие кракозябры вместо русского языка:

> Ð Ð°ÑÐ¿Ð¸ÑÐ°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ Ð·Ð°Ð½ÑÑÐ¸Ð¹ Ð¤Ð¡ÐÐ

как это исправить? Иначе дальше то, что отпарсено, читать невозможно

Comment: Добавте информации - в каком окружении, какая локаль.

Comment: @0xdb Пишу под Windows, Python 3.6, PyCharm Community 2017.1

Comment: Интересно, а что будет для print(response.content) и print(repr(web_page)). Кст, для BeautifulSoup лучше возвращать response.content -- пусть либа сама определит кодировку

Comment: @gil9red о, а вот это помогло. Спасибо)

Comment: Нуу если это устраивает вас, я оформлю это как ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте эти варианты:

```
# Байтовый массив в response.content кодируется в response.encoding
web_page = response.text
...
print(response.content)  # Байтовый массив пришедшей страницы
print(repr(web_page))  # Текстовое представление строки
```

Answer (score 1):

Кодировка данных страницы и кодировка того, куда вы эти данные выводите отличается. Могу предположить, что страница закодирована в utf-8, а выводите вы в консоль PyCharm, которая используют кодировку операционной системы по умолчанию. Для Windows это кодировка cp1251. В документации есть [целый раздел](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) посвящённый этой теме.

Самый простой способ решить эту проблему - это изменить кодировку консоли PyCharm. Для этого в каталоге, куда установлен PyCharm, рядом с pycharm.exe создайте файл `pycharm.exe.vmoptions` и вставьте в него строку `-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8`.

Другой способ - указать requests кодировку страницы:

```
response = requests.get(url)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
print(response.text)
```

Если сервер передаёт правильную кодировку в заголовке `Content-Type`, то и без этого всё должно работать нормально, но это не ваш случай.

Comment: Не помогло, все так же.

Comment: PyCharm перезапускали?

Comment: Конечно перезапустил)

Comment: Вот кстати проверил - в Content-Type страницы указана кодировка utf-8, но почему-то в `response.encoding` сразу после запроса попадает 'ISO-8859-1'. Изменение `response.encoding` на utf-8 помогает.

Comment: @insolor вы, наверное, проверили мета-тег, а requests ориентируется на заголовок http. Я проверял, в нём нет указания кодировки. Стандарт http требует, чтобы ответы без явно указанной кодировки трактовались как кодированные в ISO-8859-1. Потому крякозыблы и получаются, что requests производит кодирование из неверной исходной кодировки.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, да, похоже в заголовке http проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так. Просто добавьте в начало кода `# coding=utf-8`, должно помочь.

```
# coding=utf-8
text1=input()
text2=input()
text3=input()
```

Comment: Вставляйте код текстом, а не картинками.