# Ошибка чтения сайта с кодировкой cp1251 в python 3

Tags: python, кодировка, парсер

Пытаюсь прочитать сайт с данными о погоде http://www.pogodaiklimat.ru/weather.php?id=27612&bday=1&fday=14&amonth=1&ayear=2011
Но при попытке раскодироват текст сайта возникает ошибка

```
url = 'http://www.pogodaiklimat.ru/weather.php?id=27612&bday=1&fday=14&amonth=1&ayear=2011'
r = requests.get(url)
r.text.encode('cp1251')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 40-44: character maps to <undefined>
```

При этом, в коде сайта указано:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

Как прочитать в данном случае страницу?

Спасибо!

Comment: Возможно, дубликат: [Python 3.6 Не распознает русские символы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664484), но я точно не уверен, там ситуация немножко другая вроде

Comment: а мне кажется енкоде с декоде перепутанно)

Comment: @eri человек метод научного тыка пробовал видимо, на decode ругнулись что не найден метод — попробовал encode, всё равно не получилось — пришёл сюда)

Answer (score 1):

`r.text` содержит **уже раскодированный** текст. Не раскодированный вы можете найти в `r.content` и раскодировать вручную, но в данном случае есть вариант получше.

[Как нам сообщает официальная документация](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content), `r.text` для раскодирования использует кодировку, прописанную в `r.encoding`. Замените её на нужную, и будет вам счастье:

```
url = 'http://www.pogodaiklimat.ru/weather.php?id=27612&bday=1&fday=14&amonth=1&ayear=2011'
r = requests.get(url)
r.encoding = 'cp1251'
print(r.text)
```

Comment: так он декодированное опять кодирует зачемто